# I reset password in the recovery mode, but still unable to login in ubuntu

Tags: password-recovery

I booted in recovery mode and then typed:

```
mount -o rw,remount / passwd username
```

I got numerous options, none of them worked. Then I type `passwd` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. It asked for new password, I reset the password and exited the root system then tried to login, but it said the password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

"passwd" in recovery mode will set the root password, which is a *bad* idea. You need to use "passwd username" instead, where "username" is your actual username. Assuming your username is "u", the following two commands will do the trick:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd u
```

Also, you should reset the root password to fix what you've already done:

```
passwd -dl root
```